# ^ syntax error in awk when called via ssh

Tags: ssh, awk, syntax

I'm running filesystem usage command to detect `/var` filesystem usage beyond 80% from one host to multiple remote hosts.

My command runs fine (`df -h /var | awk '$1 > 80'`), but with `ssh` it gives me syntax errors.

```
for i in `cat /etc/gridhosts`; do ssh -n -o BatchMode=yes ${i} "df -h /var | awk '$4 > 80'" ; done
awk:  > 80
awk:  ^ syntax error
awk:  > 80
awk:  ^ syntax error
awk:  > 80
```

Comment: `$4` is being passed to ssh inside double quotes with an unescaped dollar sign. Is that intentional?

Comment: @guest $4 gets the 4th field value of df command output

Comment: $4 does NOT get the 4th field. In the top level script, the whole command starting with df is in double quotes. Inside double quotes, the single quotes around the awk program are just characters -- they are not syntactic single quotes, they do not wrap the awk script. The $4 is exposed and substituted at the client shell, and it gets replaced by nothing before the ssh is even called. The awk program is thus merely ' > 80' and it fails. That is as shown exactly and correctly in the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks @Paul_Pedant, I removed double quotes and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `$4` in the `awk` program is part of a double quoted string.  Since it is in double quotes, the (local) shell will expand it before calling `ssh`.

In the shell, `$4` is the 4th positional parameter, which most likely is empty.  The means that the `$4` in the `awk` code will be replaced by an empty string, producing an invalid `awk` program.

In this case, there is no need to run the `awk` command on the remote host.  Instead, just do

```bash
while IFS= read -r remote; do
    ssh -n -o BatchMode=yes "$remote" 'df /var' | awk 'FNR == 2 && $5 > 80'
done </etc/gridhosts
```

Note that I've changed the `awk` code to look at `$5` on line 2 rather than at `$4` on every line, as this is where the the percentage is usually located. Also, I've removed the `-h` option for `df` as it's not needed, and I've made the loop read the input file line by line rather than expanding the full contents of the file in a `for` loop header (which is inelegant, and could, in the general case, eat a lot of memory unnecessarily).

You may also be interested in evaluating Ansible or similar software, as this would make doing cluster-wide operations much easier.